# Событие "click" срабатывает 2 раза

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Такой вопрос, я вешаю слушатель на собитие **click** по тегу `<label>` и при клике это событие происходит 2 раза, в чем может быть причина?

```js
$(document).on( 'click', '.company-advs__item', function() {
    var count = countSelectedAdvantages();

    console.log(count);

    if( count  >= 10) {
        return false;
    }
});


function countSelectedAdvantages() {
    return $('#profile-form-advs .company-advs__item input:checked').length;
},
```

```html
<div class="company-advs profile-form__advs" id="profile-form-advs">
    <label class="company-advs__item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="advant_id"/>
        <div class="company-advs__bg">
            <div class="company-advs__ico"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="company-advs__name">какой-то текст</div>
    </label>
    <label class="company-advs__item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="advant_id"/>
        <div class="company-advs__bg">
            <div class="company-advs__ico"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="company-advs__name">какой-то текст</div>
    </label>
    <label class="company-advs__item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="advant_id"/>
        <div class="company-advs__bg">
            <div class="company-advs__ico"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="company-advs__name">какой-то текст</div>
    </label>
    <label class="company-advs__item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="advant_id"/>
        <div class="company-advs__bg">
            <div class="company-advs__ico"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="company-advs__name">какой-то текст</div>
    </label>
</div>
```

суть задачи в том, что у меня есть набор чекбоксов, и мне нужно запретить чекать очередной чекбокс, если уже чекнуто 10 чекбоксов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если вдруг элементы добавлены динамически, то ваш способ лучше для навешивания событий.
Клик по лейблу спускает событие до инпута.
Вешайте на input

```
$(document).on( 'click', '.company-advs__item [type=checkbox]', function() {
    var count = countSelectedAdvantages();

    console.log(count);

    if( count  >= 3) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Делайте вот так, видимо так отрабатывает объект label при клике. Ведь label ссылается на другой объект,и видимо инициализирует click на input к которому-он привязан. Отмените просто станд. действие для элемента input.

```js
$('.company-advs__item').on( 'click', function() {
    var count = countSelectedAdvantages();

    console.log(count);

    if( count  >= 10) {
        return false;
    }
});
$('.company-advs__item input').click(function(){return false})
```

```html
<div class="company-advs profile-form__advs" id="profile-form-advs">
    {foreach from=$Advantages item=Advant}
    <label class="company-advs__item">
        <input type="checkbox" name="advant_id" value="{$Advant.id}"/>
        <div class="company-advs__bg">
            <div class="company-advs__ico company-advs__ico_{$Advant.id}"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="company-advs__name">{$Advant.advant_label}</div>
    </label>
    {/foreach}
</div>
```

Или как вариант можно ещё такую вот проверочку влепить

```js
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click','.company-advs__item',function(e){
 e.target.tagName == 'LABEL' ? console.log('отработало') : ''
})
```

Comment: Можете объяснить в чем разница? Я понимаю что такое делегирование, но не совсем понимаю почему событие происходит 2 раза...

Comment: @АнатолийШевелев обновил ответ. Чуть в другом трабла